# Factoring a number $N = p * q$ when you have have found $n$, $p'$,$q'$ such that $n*N = p' * q'$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

$N = p * q$

$p$ & $q$ are primes.

You know $p'$ & $q'$ such at

$N' = p' * q'$ where $N$ divides $N'$

If there a way to proceed from here to get $p$ & $q$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p'$ and $q'$ are the result of a variant of Fermat's method, $\gcd(p',N)$ gives a nontrivial factor of $N$ which is in this case already one of the prime factors of $N$. However if $p'$ and $q'$ are just random numbers with this property, this won't help in general.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "If $p′$ and $q′$ are the result of a variant of Fermat's method"? The gcd method worked, but I didn't get them by using Fermat's method. Also which Fermat's method are you referring to?

Comment: The original method uses squares near $N$, the variant squares near $n\cdot N$ with a suitable $n$. If $x^2-n\cdot N=y^2$ , we get $x^2\equiv y^2\mod N$ and the chance is good that this leads to a nontrivial factor. I am not sure how to guarantee that we do not run in a useless congruence however, therefore my somewhat imprecise formulation.

Comment: The congruence is useful if and only if $x\ne \pm y\mod N$  holds. By the way, this is the main idea behind the powerful quadratic sieve.

Comment: I was trying to think of a simpler explanation for this - $p' = p * k$ $N = p * q$. So p is a common factor between $p'$ & $N$ - so gcd(p', N) and it will always be $p$ because the only factor other than p of N is q - so unless k is q, you will always get the right answer. Does this make sense?